# Error in inserting average value instead of NA

Tags: r

I have a data set called Hitters. I have 59 NA's in Salary table. My task is to replace NA with Averages Values in Salary table. I wrote this code:

```
hitters_num <- Hitters[, sapply(Hitters, is.numeric)][1, ]
hitters_num_imputed<-hitters_num

colMeans <- colMeans(hitters_num, na.rm = TRUE)
for (i in 1:ncol(hitters_num)) {
  col <- hitters_num[,i]
  col[is.na(col)] <- colMeans[i]
  hitters_num_imputed[,i] <- col
}

summary(hitters_num)
```

But I receive data with only one value as you can see on the screen below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill in the `NA` values with the mean value for each column, you can use `lapply` on the numeric columns (via `sapply(Hitters, is.numeric)`):

```
Hitters[sapply(Hitters, is.numeric)] <- lapply(Hitters[sapply(Hitters, is.numeric)],
                                               function(x) {
                                                 x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
                                                 x})

summary(Hitters["Salary"])

#     Salary      
# Min.   :  67.5  
# 1st Qu.: 226.2  
# Median : 535.9  
# Mean   : 535.9  
# 3rd Qu.: 700.0  
# Max.   :2460.0
```

Note the reason you were receiving only one value was because the below line in your original code only takes the first row and performs the operations on it:

```
hitters_num <- Hitters[, sapply(Hitters, is.numeric)][1, ]

#               AtBat Hits HmRun Runs RBI Walks Years CAtBat CHits CHmRun CRuns CRBI CWalks PutOuts Assists Errors   Salary
#-Andy Allanson   293   66     1   30  29    14     1    293    66      1    30   29     14     446      33     20 535.9259
```